# Users given explicit Read permission to the Site Pages Library are still able create pages from the Home Page New Button

Tags: sharepoint

This is for SharePoint Online:

In a modern team site I have added a user with contribute permissions to the site.
The Site Pages Library has Unique permissions, and I have explicitly granted the user permissions to only read.

What I have noticed

1. In the Site Pages Library, the User does not have permission to edit or create any of the pages.
2. However if the user were to navigate to page that already exists, then he can see the +New button, and create a new page from there. I would expect the +New button to be hidden since the user does not have permissions to create any pages.

Is this a known issues? Is there a workaround to hide the +New button for readers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my test, I can reproduce your issue successfully. It's by design that users with contribute permission to the site would see the "Add a page" button even though he has only read permission to the Site Pages Library. And users with read permission could not see the button even though he has contribute permission to Site pages library.

Although the user can create a new page, he cannot publish or save this page. This makes sense. If you want to hide the button, the only way is giving user read permissions to this site.

Comment: Thanks Michael, if I may comment, while this functionality might be by design, I would like to point out that it does lead the user down a false path.